# lein repl :connect 7000 gives ConnectException Connection refused

Tags: clojure, leiningen

When I just do `lein repl` it works, but when I try to connect to a host I get a refusing to connect error.

```
Connecting to nREPL at 127.0.0.1:7000
ConnectException Connection refused (Connection refused)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (PlainSocketImpl.java:-2)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
    java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:591)
    java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:540)
    java.net.Socket.<init> (Socket.java:436)
    java.net.Socket.<init> (Socket.java:213)
    clojure.tools.nrepl/connect (nrepl.clj:184)
    clojure.tools.nrepl/connect (nrepl.clj:174)
    clojure.core/apply (core.clj:646)
Bye for now!
```

I have tried messing with my `/etc/hosts`:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

But changing it did not help.

Settings:

```
MacOS 10.13.2
Leiningen 2.8.1 on Java 9.0.1 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `lein repl` will start its own nREPL and connect to that. Specifying `:connect 7000` won't *start* a REPL—it expects one to already be running on that port.

```
$ lein repl
nREPL server started on port 57535 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:57535
REPL-y 0.3.7, nREPL 0.2.12
```

In a separate session you should be able to connect to your other/running REPL:

```
$ lein repl :connect 57535
Connecting to nREPL at 127.0.0.1:57535
REPL-y 0.3.7, nREPL 0.2.12
```